# Pass custom parameter when survey complete in survey monkey V3

Tags: php, surveymonkey

I am looking for a way to get back the custom parameter "name" that is used for storing Custom Data in the SurveyMonkey system when a user completes a survey, whether that be via the Embed OR WebLink.

Any suggestions on how others have approached this?

I already saw this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708582/can-the-surveymonkey-custom-parameter-be-passed-back-via-a-survey-complete-url) But that is Version 2 in my case The  `get_respondent_list` is not in the Version 3 API. (Sorry for copy paste that same question but I am looking the same result in v3)

And Any suggestion about add signature pad includes the every Survey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to set a [custom variable](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) on your survey (URL parameters). You can also do this with the API, the docs is [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id).

Then when you have a weblink collector, if you created a custom variable called `name` then you would send the user to something like:

```
https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/2Q3RXZB?name=tester
```

Then that `name=tester` will be stored with that response in the SurveyMonkey side. You can see it when you [pull responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-id).

When you do:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<response_id>
```

You'll get a payload back with the value like this:

```
...
"custom_variables": {
    "name": "tester"
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @General Kandalaft I think I was going on the right path... it is actually paid future...I will test after I purchase premium plan...Any suggestion about Ssignature pad?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about ssignature pad, can you explain it more? Also you should be able to test out custom variables with the API with a draft application.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of using custom data (which is different than custom variables), if you don't care for the data to be passed INTO the survey itself but rather is just attached to the user. Please refer to General Kandalaft's excellent response here:
[Survey Monkey- Custom Values via API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538510/survey-monkey-custom-values-via-api-v3)